HV Cable Insulation Test
I have some 10 kV high-voltage cables and need to ensure they can tolerate high voltages. I conducted a test using a megohmmeter. For this test, I took a 10 cm piece of the 10 kV cable. I connected one probe to the insulation and another probe to the conductor of the cable. I set the megohmmeter to 500V, 2000V, and 5000V to measure the leakage current, with the timer set to 10 seconds. The leakage current measured was 70 microamps, 100 microamps, and 190 microamps, respectively. This seems acceptable, but when I tested a low-voltage cable (perhaps rated at 250V), the results were the same! I expected the leakage current of the 250V cable to be much higher than that of the HV cable. How do I conduct a test to accurately assess the insulation resistance of HV cables, ensuring that lower voltage cables do not pass the test?
EDIT: In the following figure, the connection of probs to the test cable shown.


What medium did you use as negative electrode? Air?

How does one "connect one probe to the insulation"?

How do you know that 250 V cable cant withstand 10 kV?

The connection shown in the edited version of the question.

To get a better understanding of insulations test and your readings, I highly recommend reading the
"The Complete Guide
to Electrical Insulation
Testing" by Megger.
Here are highlights for your question:

As previously mentioned, insulation resistance readings should be considered
relative. They can be quite different for one motor or machine tested three
days in a row, yet not mean bad insulation. What really matters is the trend
in readings over a time period, showing lessening resistance and warning
of coming problems. Periodic testing is, therefore, your best approach to
preventive maintenance of electrical equipment,...


Current through and along insulation is made up partly of a relatively
steady current in leakage paths over the insulation surface. Electricity
also flows through the volume of the insulation. Actually, as shown in
Fig. 5, our total current comprises three components: 1. Capacitance Charging Current
Current that starts out high and drops after the insulation has been
charged to full voltage (much like water flow in a garden hose when
you first turn on the spigot). 2. Absorption Current
Also an initially high current which then drops (for reasons discussed
under the section Time-Resistance Method). 3. Conduction or Leakage Current
A small essentially steady current both through and over the
insulation.


In this method, you simply connect the Megger instrument across the
insulation to be tested and operate it for a short, specific time period
(60 seconds is usually recommended). As shown schematically in Fig. 6,
you’ve simply picked a point on a curve of increasing resistance values;
quite often the value would be less for 30 seconds, more for 60 seconds.
Bear in mind also that temperature and humidity, as well as condition of
your insulation affect your reading.

In short, your readings are not precise, should be obtained after a good minute and will be heavily affected by humidity and temperature. You should use these more as a trendline rather then precise values.
In your case, it is more than plausible that the 250V cable might look at first glance better then the other, the trend will be in favour of the 1000V.
Also look at the materials used in your cables, maybe they are made out of the same material, but one is just certified for more voltage.
